# Converting Excel-document into 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, excel

Is there any way of taking the data from an Excel-document and putting it in a 2-dimensional array using Java? I'm interested in using the data as Strings if it makes any difference.

thanks :)

Comment: How does your excel document data look like? Do you know Apache POI? If you don't, you should :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)? Very simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pure-Java library. There are a few that are mature, although they're not completely bug-free. The best are [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/). JExcelAPI is pretty old. POI seems to have more support. I've used both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the COM API through OLE automation and get the data out that way.  [This](http://www.java-forums.org/swt-jface/26264-ole-automation-excel.html) is an example of doing it with Java.